# Python: creating a list from a string containing tags

Tags: python, slack-api, slack

If I have a string containing tags formatted like <@tag> such as:

> text = "In this test I tag <@bill>, <@Jennifer>, and lastly <@bob>."

how might I get a python list of the tags extracted for purposes of iterating through the tags.

['bill','Jennifer','bob']

While this is going to be specifically applied to a Slack Chatops Bot I am working on, I left it generic as it might be useful for other things. And I failing at how to for a decent google search to solve it, and the suggested questions in Stack Exchange did not touch on this already..

Thanks!
Nick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regular expressions:

```
import re
text = "In this test I tag <@bill>, <@Jennifer>, and lastly <@bob>."
print(re.findall('<@(.+?)>', text))  # ['bill', 'Jennifer', 'bob']
```

Basic explanation:

- `()` denotes a capturing group, i.e. 'extract this part for me'
- `.` means 'any character'
- `.+` means 'any character one or more times'
- `.+?` means 'any character one or more times, but as few as possible', otherwise it would include the `>` and many more characters after that:

`print(re.findall('<@(.+)>', text))  # ['bill>, <@Jennifer>, and lastly <@bob']`

Comment: This is the exact answer I was about to post. Guess I am not fast enough yet to compete with the pros lol.

Comment: This works best in my case and I am embarrassed for not thinking or "re" already as it is in use in my code for other things, so I am marking this as my answer. Thank you!

.